# How to write Mathematical formula with "^" (caret) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, formula

I need some help how to make this math formula in javascript. i have tried searching but couldn't really find cause  i dont even know what ^ is called in English.

Thanks in advance

```
Math.floor(20*(1.1^(x-10)));
```

Comment: Here's the [Math object documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math)

Comment: `a^b` does not raise `a` to the `b` power in JavaScript. You'll want to use `Math.pow`.

Comment: In English, people generally say `A^B` as `A to the Bth power`.  In your case, `1.1 to the (x minus 10)th power`. See also Exponentiation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation

Answer (score 3):

```
Math.floor(20*(Math.pow(1.1, (x-10))));
```

Answer (score 3):

`^` is the bitwise `XOR` operator - not what you want. Use the `Math.pow` function for exponentiation:

```
Math.floor( 20 * (Math.pow(1.1, x - 10)) );
```

Set this up in a function so you can use `x` for whatever value it may be:

```
var eq = function(x) {
    return Math.floor( 20 * (Math.pow(1.1, x - 10)) );
};
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) is what you are looking for.

`^`, as used in other languages, is called the power or exponential operator, but in Javascript, it serves a different purpose, it is the bitwise XOR operator.

Comment: `^` is the bitwise xor operator in JavaScript, although it's used differently elsewhere.

Comment: @zzzzBov My sentence implied the wrong meaning, but I fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.floor(20*(Math.pow(1.1, x - 10)));
```