# Unexpected underflow

Tags: javascript, underflow

```js
//Data
var M = 83 * (10 ^ (-5));
var R = 2077;
var Th = 1087;
var Tk = 372;
var Tr = 667;
var a = 90;
var Vclc = 9.135 * (10 ^ (-6));
var Vcle = 7.733 * (10 ^ (-6));
var Vswe = 6.105 * (10 ^ (-5));
var Vswc = 6.294 * (10 ^ (-5));
var Vk = 5.606 * (10 ^ (-6));
var Vr = 19.308 * (10 ^ (-6));
var Vh = 5.606 * (10 ^ (-6));

var ρ = ((2 * Vclc + 2 * Vk + Vswc) / (2 * Tk)) + ((Vr * Math.log(Th / Tk)) / (Th - Tk)) + ((2 * Vcle + 2 * Vh + Vswe) / (2 * Th));
console.log(ρ);
console.log(ρ < Number.MIN_VALUE);
```

When I run this code in CodePen, I get in the console: -1.4626799636897467 and true, which I think means there is an underflow. However, the value of ρ should be something like k*10^-10, where k is constant around 2000. Since the smallest positive number that can be represented in Javascript is 5e-324, which is way smaller than my value, why do I get an underflow? If it's not an underflow I don't understand how a sum of positive numbers can result in a negative number...

Note: I used information provided here for the check of underflow:[How to detect numeric overflow/underflow in JavaScript arithmetic operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164706/how-to-detect-numeric-overflow-underflow-in-javascript-arithmetic-operations) and [JavaScript MIN_VALUE Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_min_value.asp)

Comment: `^` is not exponentiation, it's bitwise XOR, so `10 ^ -5` is `-15`.

Comment: `**` or `Math.pow` are exponentiation, not `^`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write Mathematical formula with "^" (caret) in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570889/how-to-write-mathematical-formula-with-caret-in-javascript)

Comment: I am learning through freeCodeCamp which didn't feature exponentiation and since ^ is used in other languages, I wrongfully assumed it would be ^ in JS too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is bitwise XOR, not exponentiation.

You can use exponential notation to enter literal powers of 10. `xxxEyy` is `xxx * 10^yy`

```js
//Data
var M = 83e-5;
var R = 2077;
var Th = 1087;
var Tk = 372;
var Tr = 667;
var a = 90;
var Vclc = 9.135e-6;
var Vcle = 7.733e-6;
var Vswe = 6.105e-5;
var Vswc = 6.294e-5;
var Vk = 5.606e-6;
var Vr = 19.308e-6;
var Vh = 5.606e-6;

var ρ = ((2 * Vclc + 2 * Vk + Vswc) / (2 * Tk)) + ((Vr * Math.log(Th / Tk)) / (Th - Tk)) + ((2 * Vcle + 2 * Vh + Vswe) / (2 * Th));
console.log(ρ);
console.log(ρ < Number.MIN_VALUE);
```

The reason why you get `true` in your code is because `Number.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest *positive* number, but your result is negative. If you want to test for underflow, you need to check whether the absolute value of `p` is lower than `Number.MIN_VALUE`.

But since numbers smaller than this can't be represented in Javascript floating point, the test will never actually be true for anything other than `0`.